# Keras load model multiple times, no weight sharing, build model on top and save

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

How to load a **model multiple times**, **don't share weights** between them, build a new model on top and **save** the new model?

What I did:

```
def loadPretrainedModel(minuslayers, addStr):
    model = model_from_json(myModelJson)
    model.load_weights(weightsfile)
    for i in range(minusLayers):
        model.layers.pop()
        model.outputs = [model.layers[len(model.layers) - 1].output]
        model.layers[len(model.layers) - 1].outbound_nodes = []

    for layer in model.layers:
        layer.name = layer.name + addStr

    model.name = model.name + addStr
    return model


pt_model1 = loadPretrainedModel(3, "")
pt_model1 = pt_model1([newInput1])
pt_model2 = loadPretrainedModel(3, "_mod2")
pt_model2 = pt_model2([newInput2])

newModel = Concatenate(axis=1)([pt_model1, pt_model2])
newModel = Dense(180, activation='tanh')(newModel)
... More Layers ..
newModel = Model(input=[newInput1, newInput2],outputs=myOutputs)
```

I'm not able to save the new model with `newModel.save(myPath)`
Keras throws

> {KeyError}: 'out-ib_0'

The model compiles and trains, but it seems that the weights between pt_model1 and pt_model2 are shared because the weight names in debug mode are the same.

Comment: I don't see why it should share the weights. How did you conclude that the weights are shared after training? Are they identical? If they are, are you sure that you are providing different inputs to both the models?

Comment: In debug mode the weight names of both pt_models are the same. I don't know the numerical weights however.